# C++ rectangle() parameters

Tags: c++, rectangles

I am learning to code windows forms, and am starting to use basic graphics. I am able to draw rectangles onto the screen quite easily. The problem is, I have been experimenting with changing the arguments to the constructor, and I have absolutely no idea what they do. I have googled for quite a while trying to find out, and I am completely stuck. Can someone tell me what the arguments do to the dimensions of the rectangle and its coordinates?

Say we are drawing the rectangle like this:

`Rectangle(hdc,5,5,50,50);`

Answer (score 3):

You can find the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162898(v=vs.85).aspx

```
BOOL Rectangle(
  _In_  HDC hdc,
  _In_  int nLeftRect,
  _In_  int nTopRect,
  _In_  int nRightRect,
  _In_  int nBottomRect
);
```

**Parameters**

```
hdc [in]
    A handle to the device context.

nLeftRect [in]
    The x-coordinate, in logical coordinates, of the upper-left 
    corner of the rectangle.

nTopRect [in]
    The y-coordinate, in logical coordinates, of the upper-left 
    corner of the rectangle.

nRightRect [in]
    The x-coordinate, in logical coordinates, of the lower-right 
    corner of the rectangle.

nBottomRect [in]
    The y-coordinate, in logical coordinates, of the lower-right 
    corner of the rectangle.
```

By the way, this is the first result on Google when searching for "c++ Rectangle"

Comment: Thank you, and trust me, I searched for a long time and could find nothing; this is not one of those questions which are because people didn't bother to do any research